# Hyperledger sawtooth block always pending

Tags: python-3.x, hyperledger-sawtooth

I've recently taken part in the code of the simple wallet example of hyperledger sawtooth, and the first block gets stuck on pending, I don't know why?

This is the code of the block that is returned

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "49e10b5dc3da0d9057598fcd9812ec9b3e088a8d5ba895652488a5c40696da3945671979aa906c08be25d68bb8ac1c85a1eff83ca2c48e72dd7a20903bd9d455",
      "invalid_transactions": [],
      "status": "PENDING"
    }
  ],
  "link": "http://localhost:8008/batch_statuses?id=49e10b5dc3da0d9057598fcd9812ec9b3e088a8d5ba895652488a5c40696da3945671979aa906c08be25d68bb8ac1c85a1eff83ca2c48e72dd7a20903bd9d455"
}
```

This is my batch, that I am sending

```
batches {
  header: "\nB02509850594914b74283b3deb2139355e377da0451da4305974450fd0c63f6b7d9\022\200\0011766e0daa0bededb9e43b46a234a88c96a011cbb788fcaac8b55ad94be9b4ea039b1424a205bfa13e29904d2ee7bc18c570aaa7ba0040d144dfceb8d108782bf"
  header_signature: "5afe7759d56124558f4a2f312b51327c672c3675eef34c1a2aa881786df98eaf3908558a5c3da5ed3eec555fab5754f42dd3d9ed1bce67213ba28f811b4577df"
  transactions {
    header: "\nB02509850594914b74283b3deb2139355e377da0451da4305974450fd0c63f6b7d9\032\006BMSNET\"\0031.0*Fed74e3d66e72d849b77bef7e5c9c1ae45c9c99e405c45e4c7896e6418ebaf376fda5722\0240x1.269f5f80f9370p-1:Fed74e3d66e72d849b77bef7e5c9c1ae45c9c99e405c45e4c7896e6418ebaf376fda572J\200\00105bd2c1e7c4276b640d19c4ffcc0dab743c6b77181be1893cdb75dca7e2248f27efacdc5218f6e97ba06597ae573341fc22859aec785a26003d79ca143754c2bRB02509850594914b74283b3deb2139355e377da0451da4305974450fd0c63f6b7d9"
    header_signature: "1766e0daa0bededb9e43b46a234a88c96a011cbb788fcaac8b55ad94be9b4ea039b1424a205bfa13e29904d2ee7bc18c570aaa7ba0040d144dfceb8d108782bf"
    payload: "deposit,1000"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more information, what partial code did you take from the example implementation? How does your deployment file look like? BTW, I will update the question and replace `block` with `batch`.

Comment: I've used the simplewallet example but I've extract the code and Im not using docker.

Comment: I see. The issue is not with respect to the code here. If a batch is pending then validator is not processing your transactions. Please check if you're setting up the network as documented here https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html#using-ubuntu-for-a-single-sawtooth-node . You'll have to look into the validator logs, consensus engine logs.

Comment: Thanks @Arun, I'll be checking that now!

Answer (score 1):

for me the problem was that there was `poet-validator-registry-tp`component registered in the validator. Once I removed the component the system probably went to devMode so only 1 validator was needed to able to validate the request.